# Strange smell coming from main sewage pipe in wall

Tags: pipe, smell, sewage

[image][image][image]I recently had my kitchen redone and new plumbing done. I am noticing a smell behind the dishwasher where the main sewage pipe is. It’s in the wall but partially comes and connects to other pipes. Whenever the air comes on there is a weird smell around that area. Not sure if it’s the pipe emitting this odor? [image]

Comment: Nothing we can do from here. Maybe a damaged pipe during the renovation. You're going to have to do more investigating before cutting open the wall.

Comment: diy-wise, it could be a vent or a dried out trap that's causing the issue.

Comment: the fumes rise, so the problem might be lower

Comment: @AB what exactly is your question? ... for some reason you stuck a question mark on a sentence that is not a question

Comment: My question is what could the smell be? The plumbing was repaired. And all drywall replaced. Could I just be smelling the inside of the drywall because of the cut out around the pipe?I attached a picture of what the pipe looked like before and what it looks like after. Drywall now has been put around as well as cabinets and counter tops.

Comment: Go to a local DIY store and smell some drywall. If that's the same smell you get at home, then it's drywall. It could also be the drywall joint compound that you smell, but that should go away in a few days. If it's not that, what kind of smell are you getting? Does it smell like sewage or rotten eggs? If so, then there's probably a leak in your waste plumbing. If it's a different kind of smell, then that's probably not it and you'll have to identify the _kind_ of smell in order to hunt down the source.

Comment: Also, some better labeling of the "before" and "after" pics would help. In the pic with the browner circle, it looks like there's a hose clamp on a Fernco™ in there - it's possible that the hose clamps on either end aren't tight enough. That would be more of an issue than just a bit of a smell, though, as you'd end up with a leak.

Comment: Sorry I’m not great at this app. The first picture was after , second was before and last 2 are after. The pipe is enclosed now behind the new drywall and counters/cabinets. There’s just a small cut out in the drywall for the pipe to go through the bottoms cabinet and underneath of the kitchen sink. It doesn’t smell like sewage. More of like a sweet smell like wood. But also a little musty. The drywall has been done for 2 weeks.